# How to install the most common plugins?

Tags: plugins, multimedia, ubuntu-restricted-extras

How can I install the most used plugins like flash player and mp3 in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` by clicking the button below:

[image: Install via the software center]

This will install a bunch of useful stuff, because it is a meta-package, like Flash, MP3 capability, mscorefonts etc.

Connect to the internet. Open the software center and search for `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and install it.

You will have to accept some licences for non-free stuff.

Comment: They are non-free.

Answer (score 2):

First step read this from Ubuntu 
[RestrictedFormats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats).

Then go to
[ubuntuguide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Maverick). 
This is for Maverick - there are different guides for older versions of Ubuntu.

To install Flash search for 'Flash' in the Software Centre and install it or install the package: [flashplugin-nonfree](http://packages.ubuntu.com/flashplugin-nonfree)

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Answer (score 1):

For Flash Player, try installing `flashplugin-installer` and `flashplugin-nonfree`

For the MP3 stuff, support to listen to MP3 media files should already be loaded into the system, as was my experience with 10.04 and 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only free and open-source package (without enabling [Multiverse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Multiverse)) then following helps you which  are available on [Universe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Universe) repository

For supporting MP3 most common audios & videos:-

- **`gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3`**: This GStreamer 1.0 plugin permits decoding of MPEG 1 audio layer III streams.
- **`gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`** and **`gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`** : [gstreamer plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer#Plug-ins)
- **`gstreamer1.0-libav`**: This GStreamer plugin supports a large number of audio and video compression formats through the use of the libav library.
  The plugin contains GStreamer elements for encoding 40+ formats (MPEG, DivX, MPEG4, AC3, DV, ...), decoding elements for decoding 90+ formats (AVI, MPEG, OGG, Matroska, ASF, ...), demuxing 30+ formats and colorspace conversion.

Flash player & plugin:-

- **`gnash`** :GNU Shockwave Flash (SWF) player
- **`browser-plugin-gnash`** : GNU Shockwave Flash (SWF) player - Plugin for Mozilla and derivatives

Comment: Worked well! installed only what was needed for the mp3 playback

Answer (score 0):

On every new install of Ubuntu I always use [Medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org/repository.php) in addition to the restricted extras.