# How do I get my mp3 and video codecs?

Tags: plugins, media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the flash player and Mp3 plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30163/how-to-install-the-flash-player-and-mp3-plugins)

I've recently replaced my hdd, and installed  Lucid Lynx, but while setting up my environment I realized that I can't play MP3's or video files.

My computer tries to download plugins, but keeps giving me the following error:

> E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
>   E: Unable to lock the download directory

Someone please help.

Comment: Agreed mostly.  I think it's a combination of how to install plug-ins and package lock. http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock ... either way it's a dupe

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

The failure to get archive lock means your auto update was probably running at the same time you entered the apt-get command or some similar situation. Wait a few minutes for it to complete and then try it again