# How to install mp3 plugin?

Tags: music-player

I just installed Ubuntu desktop 13.04 in my computer, dual boot with windows 7.

How to install mp3 plugin? Because I want to listen to music and watch movie, but the player requires plugin? How to solve this problem?

Comment: One question only. Please create another question for your 2nd question.

Comment: for the first question: see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/30164/47206)

Comment: more on 'restricted' formats - see [here the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu-restricted-extras) and [here the ubuntu page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)

Answer (score 5):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Hope it works!

Comment: It work on fresh install, it also install unrar, flashplayer-install, MS fonts, mpeg2 and other libs.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to open terminal and run following command to install mp3 library:

`$ sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0`

2) I don't think so. On the contrast, I think network speed is higher than Windows because of more efficient network applications. If you feel software update slow, you can change repository source by detecting the fastest source automatically.

Comment: it takes such a long time to download even vlc player...

Comment: @Khairul - this is related to your second problem, on the internet, which seems more serious. create a separate question on that and try to give more details

Comment: This don't work, I have it installed (be default) and mp3 don't work.