# Codec Support to play mp3

Tags: multimedia

I have installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` but still `mp3` format can't be played through `rhythmbox`
The error coming is:

REQUIRED PLUGIN IS NOT FOUND :: Rhythmbox requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install the most common plugins?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30163/how-to-install-the-most-common-plugins)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following, you will need to open **Terminal**:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Enter your password when prompted, then press **Enter** again to complete the action

That will remove the Ubuntu Restricted Extras package, now you will need to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Now you have reinstalled the Ubuntu Restricted Extras package, could you please launch Rhythmbox and try playing a track.

Answer (score 2):

You can always install `vlc` which is a good and popular Media Player having support for many file formats.

`vlc` can be installed by entering these commands in **Terminal**

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Then you can run your `.mp3` file with vlc