# How can I play music?

Tags: 14.04, sound, codecs

I use Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn. When I try to play music (audio/video), it shows error "Required plugin could not be found

Rhythmbox requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder"

How can I fix it?

Comment: The error message doesn't let you install any plugin?

Comment: same of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/367439/codec-support-to-play-mp3?lq=1

Comment: Can't install VLC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to install sound plugins. The easiest way is to:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

That should fix it, and install some other useful things along with it (e.g Adobe Flash).

Comment: I did that, I was not working, now it's good!

Answer (score 0):

Yo can install Vlc to listen music by

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Or find this [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367439/codec-support-to-play-mp3)