# How to get rid of this error

Tags: sound, video, plugins, multimedia

> The Required plugins could not be found
>
> Videos requires to install plugins to play files of the following types:
> •  MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder
> •  MPEG-4 Video decoder

I tried manually installing the same plugins, but it didn't do anything.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: **Vote-to-close:** [How to install the most common plugins?](http://askubuntu.com/q/30163/40581)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`? Although try installing videoplayers VLC and SMplayer, they have bundled plugin version with them.

Comment: > murtaza@murtaza-Presario-CQ57-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for murtaza: 
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
> 
> murtaza@murtaza-Presario-CQ57-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: Again in case of typo: `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. This thing can not not to be there. If it isn't, your repos list is damaged and that is the source of the error you see. Repair repos and install this.

Comment: How to change my source? What available sources can I download from?

Comment: [These are basics.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: thank you, it worked, actually the problem was with my source, changed source to main server and it worked, thank you once again, really you guys have motivated me to use Ubuntu more than Windows. :D