# you tube downloder

Tags: system-installation

Hi i just get rid of windows and i have installed Ubuntu. I have two questions:

1. I'm trying to download you tube to mp3 and when it starts is says that some files are missing from Ubuntu.
2. I downloaded all video downloader and when i paste the link it says
   that can not found the link.

Thanks a lot Dimitris

Comment: To install youtube-to-mp3: http://www.mediahuman.com/repository.html

Comment: 1) Those are statements, not question. Please rephrase your question to contain an actual question. 2) We cannot help you, unless you describe what you did, what you tried to achieve and what happened instead in as much detail as possible. At the very least include the verbatim error and warning messages that you encountered. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

for mp3 playback ,you first have to install the required plugins because they are not free and not included in ubuntu by default.
[refet to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30163/how-to-install-the-most-common-plugins) to read more

enabling the multiverse source in your `/etc/apt/source.list` and a simple

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` should get you going.

for Youtube videos ,  use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#installation) , it's a python script

downloading is as simple as `youtube-dl "youtube-video-url"` , by default it downloads the highest quality available.

it supports downloading from playlists,with subtitles and combining dash videos, meaning you can have a low quality video with high quality audio etc.

to see what formats exist for a video `youtube-dl -F "utube-video-url"`

[image]

you now just have to select the combinaison of video+audio you like

`youtube-dl -f 135+171 "url"`

or

`youtube-dl -f 135+bestaudio "url"`

`youtube-dl -f worstvideo+171 "url"`

this downloads the audio only, note that you won't have an mp3 file but either a `.webm` , `.mp4` or a `.mp4a` with audio only.

`youtube-dl -f bestaudio "url"`

Comment: didn't know about that youtube-dl script. Thank you. I think it's worth it to look into the source code deeper and to contribute to the project.

Answer (score 0):

"ClipGrab" is a amazing web video downloader. You can even search youtube videos in it! To install it:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install clipgrab`

And it should be in the Dash!