# Can not play music with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, music

I am trying to get away from MS Windows.  I am new to Ubuntu and really like it a lot.  I am having a problem with version 16.04; When I attempt to play a song, the system opens the video player and then says it needs to load plugins.  I have tried to associate my songs with Rhythm-box but I can not get them to play.  Would anyone know how to resolve this issue?  I need some hand holding here.  Thanks!

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats and if that does not work, what file are you trying to play ? mp3 ? wav ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the most common plugins?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30163/how-to-install-the-most-common-plugins)

Answer (score 1):

Open the Dash and launch a Terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras && sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

Enter your password to complete the installation.

More info [HERE](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/multimedia)